# Finding distance between analog stick center and current position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'd like to find out how far the player is pushing an Xbox controller analogue 
stick. I don't need to know the angle it is being pushed, just how far. I'd like it to return a value of 0 to 1. Here are some examples!

- If the player was pushing the stick fully down it would return 1.
- If the stick was in the center it would return 0.
- If they were pushing the stick to its full extent but at a 45 degree angle it would still return 1.
- If they were pushing the stick only halfway and at a 135 degree angle it would return 0.5

Code I have tried so far

```
new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"),Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical")).magnitude
```

and I tried this code, despite not really understanding it :-/

```
    float xAxis = (Input.GetAxis ("Player" + padNumber + "Horizontal"));
    float yAxis = (Input.GetAxis ("Player" + padNumber + "Vertical"));

    thumbStickDistance = Mathf.Sqrt(Mathf.Abs((xAxis*xAxis)+(yAxis*yAxis)));
```

However - Both these return different values depending on the angle the stick is pushed.

Comment: That's just the Pythagorean distance formula. You shouldn't need the Abs() call either. You just need to divide by the max axis value to convert to a range from 0 to 1.

Comment: I looked at the documentation and it's clear that GetAxisRaw and GetAxis are different functions. I think that explains the different values but I really know nothing about Unity.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm not so great at Maths and quite a beginner at programming. How would I do what you're suggesting?

Comment: I think the two versions will likely match it you used the same axis function in each. I have a feeling the second one is the one you want though. It looks like the range of values is already -1 to 1 so there won't be a need for any division after all.

Comment: Using both versions will give me a range that is different depending what angle the stick is. And neither will give me a range between 0 and 1. Ive tested them both, thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: It will help the next person to know what values you _are_ getting. Did you use the GetAxis function in your last tests?

Comment: Yes i did. When pushing up and left i will get in the ranges of 3, straight up around 1, up and right around 3. Right is about 1. Etc.

Answer (score 0):

You have the answer, but you might think you don't because you are expecting to see different values. The magnitude is what you want.

First of all, your formula for thumbStickDistance is exactly what the magnitude property for a Vector2 does. Second, the difference between GetAxis and GetAxisRaw is that GetAxis applies some smoothing. This is best seen if you use the arrow keys. GetAxis will rise and fall, whereas GetAxisRaw will jump to -1, 0 or 1 immediately. Which you use for the xbox controller doesn't matter much.

Now, both the horizontal and vertical axes are in the range -1;1. If the xbox controller joystick had a square movement area then you could have both axes at 1 and the maximum distance you could measure would be sqrt(2) or about 1.414. If the controller had a perfectly circular movement area then the maximum distance you could measure would be 1 no matter which direction you pushed it in. As it turns out, although the xbox controller is closer to circular than square, it is neither. The maximum distance i was able to measure was about 1.16 which means that i reached a point just outside the circle around the centre.

So my advice would be to use the magnitude and if you need it use [Clamp01](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Clamp01.html) to limit the value to not exceed 1. The alternative would be to calibrate the controller, which could be complicated and it would need to be done each time you switch controllers as there are bound to be differences even between two otherwise identical xbox controllers.